# How do I apply the same styling to all immediate children classes?

Tags: css, tags, less, styling

In [less](http://lesscss.org/) I have the following:

```
.some-class{
    > li{
        a{

            color: white; 
            background: @fti-lightgrey;
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding: 1px 15px;

            // a color for the partcular tab that is chosen. (the color for each tab can be set inside mura)
            &.orange{ 
                &:hover{ background: @fti-orange; }
                &:hover{ color: white; }
            }
            &.black { 
                &:hover{ background: black; }
                &:hover{ color: white; }
            }
            &.topaz{ 
                &:hover{ background: @fti-topaz; }
                &:hover{ color: white; }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

How do I avoid writing `&:hover{ color: white; }` multiple times?
Is there a way to apply this line to all of the immediate class descendants somewhere inside the `a` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the desired result.

Do you want:
1) White hover color by default, regardless of whether it also has the one of the .orange, .black, or .topaz classes?

```
.some-class{
> li{
    a{

        color: white; 
        background: @fti-lightgrey;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 1px 15px;

        // a color for the partcular tab that is chosen. (the color for each tab can be set inside mura)
        &.orange{ 
            &:hover{ background: @fti-orange; }
        }
        &.black { 
            &:hover{ background: black; }
        }
        &.topaz{ 
            &:hover{ background: @fti-topaz; }
        }

    }
    a:hover{ color: white; }
}
```

}

2) Or do you *only* want it to be white on hover if it *also* has one of .orange, .black, .topaz classes?

```
.some-class{
> li{
    a{

        color: white; 
        background: @fti-lightgrey;
        border-radius: 0px;
        padding: 1px 15px;

        // a color for the partcular tab that is chosen. (the color for each tab can be set inside mura)
        &.orange{ 
            &:hover{ background: @fti-orange; }
        }
        &.black { 
            &:hover{ background: black; }
        }
        &.topaz{ 
            &:hover{ background: @fti-topaz; }
        }

    }
    a:hover {
        &.orange, &.black, &.topaz{ 
            color: white; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
a:hover {
    &.orange, 
    &.black,
    &.topaz { color: white; }
}
```

then define the background individually. This is assuming the hover for your anchor is different colour than white by default and you want the coloured classes to be white(not in a human race way!).

or use the same style as you have

```
a {
    &.orange, &.black, &.topaz {
        &:hover { color: white; }
    }
}
```

if you have a common class for the colours then you could always target that common class

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend to simply remove `&:hover { color: white; }` rules, as long as you have it set on `a` tag already and there is no something like `a:hover` rules which might override this.

In case if you have some `a:hover` rule with different color, simply add `&:hover { color: white }` right inside of `a` block.

```
.some-class{
    > li{
        a{
            color: white; 
            background: @fti-lightgrey;
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding: 1px 15px;

            // a color for the partcular tab that is chosen. (the color for each tab can be set inside mura)
            &.orange{ 
                &:hover{ background: @fti-orange; }
            }
            &.black { 
                &:hover{ background: black; }
            }
            &.topaz{ 
                &:hover{ background: @fti-topaz; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```